# Mule HTTP Connector: When HTTP param is Payload or inboundProperties

Tags: mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio

We have two links about Mule HTTP Connector:

**HTTP Params is inboundProperties**
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/http-listener-connector#http-custom-properties-request-line

**HTTP Params is Payload**
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/migrating-to-the-new-http-connector#mapping-an-http-message-to-a-mule-message

I would like to understand the differences and which is the correct for HTTP Connector in Mule 3.8.0.

Answer (score 1):

Both examples are correct and apply to Mule 3.8.0, but they are different examples.

The first example is only referring to request line parameters, which are all mapped to inbound properties.

The second example features the above request line parameters, as well as a application/x-www-form-urlencoded body, which is mapped to the payload.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zv8rVrCWVSU

here is video about http connector in mule 
how to add headers in http connector